# GridView will disappear upon scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

When I scroll my GridView up and down, the gridview will start lose its children and eventually (intermittently) the whole gridview will dissapear on bottom of page if I done too many scroll.

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Item> list;

    public Adapter(Context _context, List<Item> _list){
        this.context = _context;
        this.list = _list;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size() - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView itemLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, .., null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(..);
            holder.itemLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(..);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Item item = list.get(position + 1);
        holder.itemLabel.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(item.getImage());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

What could be wrong, as my adapter is a standard adapter?

Comment: have you given match_parent or wrap_content height or width to the imageview? If so, try to give fixed height and width or give dynamically based on device screen size. It should be resolved! Or  Use recyclerview instead of gridview for better approach!

Comment: Unfortunately we don't want to use compat library yet :(

Comment: Then try to set height and width dynamically issue will be resolved!

Comment: most likely it's not because of height or width.. since the grid view itself is completely gone.

Comment: Gridview should never be gone. the custom items which you are trying to bind into it it should be gone. set background color to gridview and then test it!

Comment: Well after trying, actually the gridview is still there, however, all children are gone!

Comment: That's what I commented! Now give fixed height to your child imageview and then try! it will be fixed!